# How can I achieve this layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to create this layout where there are three equal ImageViews in a linear layout with layout_weight = 1.0 each. I just want to put two circular images on the inner edges aligned center vertically in android. Maybe I cant achieve this in XML or maybe yes. Please help me achieving this [image]properly.

Comment: use `FrameLayout` to contain these evenly distributed ImageViews and add a button to it giving a `gravity` of `center` and some `marginLeft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="right">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="left">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: But its not perfect in every device

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#123456"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#654321"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
 </FrameLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Look This]